# Model Derivative API revit to dwg

Tags: revit-api, autodesk, forge, dwg

I wanted to convert the Revit file to DWG file, so I created a job using the Model Derivative API, When I check the Manifest, Progress will succeed at 0%.

The following json was used to create the job

```
{
  "input" : {
    "urn" : "****************************"
  },
  "output" : {
    "formats" : [
      {
        "type" : "dwg"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```